# how to change the encoding of a JSON-file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, utf-16

I've used flash CS6 to export an animation to a spritesheet. This gives me 2 files: a png and a json file.

this is a simplified version of the json:

```
{"frames": 
{
    "movieclip 10000":
    {
        "frame": {"x":676,"y":0,"w":164,"h":280},
        "rotated": false,
        "trimmed": false,
        "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":164,"h":280},
        "sourceSize": {"w":164,"h":280}
    },
    …
    "movieclip 10004":
    {
        "frame": {"x":671,"y":280,"w":164,"h":280},
        "rotated": false,
        "trimmed": false,
        "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":164,"h":280},
        "sourceSize": {"w":164,"h":280}
    }
},
"meta": {
    "app": "Adobe Flash CS6",
    "version": "12.0.2.529",
    "image": "boom1 8B4 def.png",
    "format": "RGBA8888",
    "size": {"w":1024,"h":1000},
    "scale": "1"
}
```

Nothing special here. But the file is encoded in (according to textwrangler) UTF-16 Little Endian.
This doesn't give any problems in Chrome, but when parsing the json in FF I get a "parsererror".

When I change the encoding of the file, it works without any problem in firefox.

**So here is my question**: (How) can I change the encoding using javascript?

this snippet is how I load my json:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this.json,
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        that.jsonLoadHandler(json);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        that.errorHandler(xhr, textStatus);
    }
});
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I dont think you can change the encoding of the file. Depends on how it was saved. You will likely need to do this on the server side.

Comment: Would it work if you serve it as utf-16 and set the contentType as utf-16 too ?

Comment: @techfoobar: on serverside this would be a breeze using php. It's just that I would like to be able to this clientside. Because at the moment I'm doing it just clientside with hardlinked assets.

Comment: @dystroy: That didn't change anything. But was well worth a shot.

Comment: As you generated your file once and it doesn't seem to be something you plan to do again, can't you open the file in an editor and save it as UTF-8 (and without BOM) ?

Comment: Problem is I have literally hundreds of files to parse. saving them all as UTF-8 would be an anoying job. I'll just have to parse the file serverside before I serve it to the client.

Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
use only
contentType: "application/json;" this may resolve your problem.